# Extract text by making boxes on each line using python

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I am new in python I want to extract text from the image I'm using tesseract library It's not detecting correct words when I pass the image So now I want to make boxes on each line of the image, extract and save boxes of the line into jpeg file. but I don't know how to make bounding boxes line by line as it's making every where.Hence this is the image I'm working on it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6YfM.jpg

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread('1.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\\ProgramData\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
from pytesseract import Output
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if(d['text'][i] != ""):
        (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
print(pytesseract.image_to_data(img))
cv2.imshow('result.png', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ??

Comment: First I simply try this line  print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img) so it's not working afterward I used the code which I uploaded here

Comment: you need to do some operations on image to make it more readable and then try to get the contour drawn, then use pytesseract.

Comment: What operation should I have to perform?

Comment: you can follow this https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/